# Broadcast receiver invoke when another applications a particular activity is opened

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation, broadcastreceiver

I wand a `Broadcast receiver` invoke when another applications a particular `activity` is opened in android. For example When `Navigation` page in `Map` application that installed in `android` phone, When opened and showing the Navigation, I want to show a `Toast` that display "Currently showing Navigation". So how can I achieve that?

Comment: There is something called as AccessibilityService which will help you to achive your goal but it has to enabled by users from settings under Accessibility. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html

Answer (score 0):

This below code will help you to identify windo change event

```
public class AccessibilityEventService
        extends AccessibilityService {

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED)
            Log.i("op",event.getPackageName());
    }

}
```

but it has to enabled by users from Accessibility  under settings.
or You can check current top activity in a time gap using following code

```
 ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

// get the info from the currently running task
List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);

Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Activity ::"
        + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());

ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
    componentInfo.getPackageName();
```

Answer (score -1):

As my understood that you need to show a toast on onRecieve Fuunction

```
Toast.makeText(context,"your text",2000).show();
//context is input parameter from onRecieve function
```